# How to create template of the routes set in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm using ajax for CRUD and in every model I must set all actions but only "get" types, like this

```
get "brands/create"
get "brands/update"
get "brands/new"
get "brands/edit"
get "brands/destroy"
```

How can I create a set of manes that I'm using, just for avoid duplicating.

And the second point - when I'm trying to use `resources :brands` (i can send ajax request for default types like. does it correct way?), there standard redirects works but I don't want to change it for html in every action, cause I don't use it at all. Now I don't render any, actions run automatically.

Comment: Why do you have to use `GET`?

Comment: What is the difference? Anyway I can't use resources.

Comment: The difference between using only `GET` and using `GET/POST` is almost the same as doing skydiving without parachute or with one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you REALLY, REALLY, REEEALLY should not do only GET because it leaves your application very vulnerable. I can give an example further down why you should not but first a solution to the actual question.

To make your routes a little more DRY you can create custom route helpers in a separate module and use them. Start by creating a `route_helpers.rb` in your `RAILS_ROOT/lib` folder and then make it look something like this:

```
class ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper

  def my_resources(*args)
    args.each do |res|
      get "#{res}/create"
      get "#{res}/update"
      get "#{res}/new"
      get "#{res}/edit"
      get "#{res}/destroy"
    end
  end
end
```

And then you can use routes in your routes.rb like this:

```
require 'route_helpers'

AppName::Application.routes.draw do

  my_resources :brands

end
```

And don't forget to require the route_helpers like in my example.

And now, DO NOT!!! do it like in my example. I agree that it is good to not repeat yourself but there is a reason why the standard resources generates routes the way it does. GET is for reading only, not creating, updating and certainly not destroying records.

If you create links to destroy an item and a search engine starts crawling your site to index it, it will follow the link with the get command and BAM.... your record is deleted.
If you have login to your site to prevent that, then it could also happen if your user is logged in and then in another tab visits my page where I have an img tag and I set the src of that to yourdomain.com/brands/destroy then the users browser with the logged in session will try to get and download an image and BAM..... your record is deleted again.

This is just a few examples but the point remains, for your own sake, do not use the GET protocol this way.

Comment: Thanks, now I understood why not using only GET.